# Basic question in the radical of an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Does the radical of an ideal $\sqrt{I}$ always contain $I$? I think the question boils down to if we are given $\sqrt{I}$, does it contain all the elements such that raised to ANY power? So $x \in \sqrt{I}$ implies $x^n \in I$ for all $n$, or given a specific $n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition is $\sqrt{I} := \{ x\in R \ | \ x^n \in I \text{ for some } n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ So an element $x\in R$ is in $\sqrt{I}$ if some power of it lies in $I,$ which is trivially true for the elements of $I.$

Comment: Did you mean that *it is trivially true* **for the generators of I**?

Comment: @freehumorist No, I did in fact mean it for all elements of $I,$ not just the generators.

Comment: Alright, I now saw what I didn't get. Then, I reformulate my question: Can we say that $ \sqrt{I} $ is the set of generators of I? Indeed, this is incomplete, maybe we may say that $ \sqrt{I} $ is the set of any linear combination of generators of $I$, which still remain irreducible. does it make any sense?